# What is the bit rate?

Tags: audio, bitrate

I am new to audio programming,
But I am wondering formula of bitRate,

According to wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate#Audio,

```
bit rate = sample rate X bit depth X channels
```

and

- **sample rate** is the number of samples (or snapshots taken) per second obtained by a digital audio device.
- **bit depth** is the number of bits of information in each sample.

So why `bit rate = sample rate X bit depth X channels`?

From my perspective, if `bitDepth = 2` bit, `sample rate = 3 HZ`
then I can transfer 6 bit data in 1 second

For example:

```
Sample data = 00 //at 1/3 second.  
Sample data = 01 //at 2/3 second.  
Sample data = 10 //at 3/3 second.
```

So I transfer `000110` in 1 second, is that correct logic?

Comment: Would "yes" be a sufficient answer to this question?

Comment: What’s the question? Are you asking whether 2 x 3 is 6?

Answer (score 1):

Bit-rate is the **expected** amount of bits per interval (eg: per second).

Sound cycles are measured in hertz, where `1 hertz == 1 second`. So to get full sound data that represents that 1 second of audio, you calculate how many bits are needed to be sent (or for media players, they check the bit-rate in a file-format's settings so they can read & playback correctly).

> Why is channels involved (isn't `sample rate X bit-depth` enough)?

In digital audio the samples are sent for each "ear" (L/R channel). There will always be **double** the amount of samples in a stereo sound versus if it was mono sound. Usually there is a "flag" to specify if sound is stereo or mono.

Logic Example: (without bit-depth, and assuming 1-bit per sample)...

There is speech "Hello" recorded at 200 samples/sec at bitrate of 100/sec. What happens?

- If stereo flag, each ear gets 100 samples per sec (correct total of 200 played)
- If mono, audio speech will sound slow by half (since only 100 samples played at  expected bit-rate of 100, but remember, a full second was recorded at 200 sample/sec. You get half of "hello" in one second and the other at next second to (== slowed speech).

Taking the above example, you will find these *`audio gives slow/double speed`* adventures in your *"new to audio programming"* experience. The fix will be either setting channels amount or setting bit-rate correctly. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The 'sample rate' is the rate at which **each** channel is sampled.

So 'sample rate X bit depth' will give you the bit rate for a single channel.

You then need to multiply that by the number of channels to get the total bit rate flowing through the system.

For example the CD standard has a sample rate of 44100 samples per second and a bit depth of 16 giving a bit rate of 705600 per channel and a total bit rate of 1411200 bits per seconds for stereo.